# Pytorch-forecasting:: Univariate AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, pytorch-forecasting

I tried to do univariate forecasting with Pytorch-Forecasting.

But I got following error on TimeSeriesDataSet

> AssertionError: filters should not remove entries all entries - check
> encoder/decoder lengths and lags

I have tried googling for the error, read the suggestion and make sure my training_df has sufficient number of rows. (I have plenty: 196). Also I only has 1 group_id which is 1. No other group_id, so all those 196 should be in same group.

My dataframes sample:

note: all rows has same group value = 1

> ```
>     PutCall_Ratio_Total  time_idx  group
> ```
>
> Date
> 2006-02-24    11119.140000    0         1
> 2006-02-25    7436.316667     1         1
> 2006-02-26    3753.493333     2         1

I have training_df with length of 196

> > len(training_df)
> > 196

And here is my TimeSeriesDataSet portion:

````
 context_length = 28*7
 prediction_length = 7 
     # setup Pytorch Forecasting TimeSeriesDataSet for training data
     training_data = TimeSeriesDataSet(
         training_df,
         time_idx="time_idx",
         target="PutCall_Ratio_Total",
         group_ids=["group"],
         time_varying_unknown_reals=["PutCall_Ratio_Total"],
         max_encoder_length=context_length,
         max_prediction_length=prediction_length
     )```
````

Comment: I tried to make it multivariate by put back other columns I removed before, but still same error as above. My attempt use the following data: 

  ```df1_vixo.head(3)
  
PutCall_Ratio VIX Put Volume VIX Call Volume Total PutCall_Ratio_Total time_idx group
Date       
2006-02-24 1.18 5095.000000 4328.000000 9423.000000 11119.140000 0 1
2006-02-25 0.79 3420.333333 5217.333333 8637.666667 7436.316667 1 1
2006-02-26 0.40 1745.666667 6106.666667 7852.333333 3753.493333 2 1```

Answer (score 1):

After some experiment, it seems that the training_df length (196) should be larger
than or equal to (context_length + prediction_length).

So for example above it works once I update the context_length to 27 * 7 instead of 28 * 7.

Since 27 * 7 + 7 = 196.
While 28 * 7 + 7 > 196.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the solution was to drop higher lags `lags={'target': [7, 30]}` instead of `lags={'target': [7, 30, 365]}`, because some timeseries were short enough